# i want to prevent user from shifting in my web by writing url manually by php

Tags: php

i have main page and form this page there is some button "each button will refer the user to the correct page after click on it" i want to use PHP to prevent user from writing the URL manually also i used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's not working with all browsers.

Comment: Ultimately you can't. What exactly is the problem should the user navigate to some specific URL directly? Likely you want to implement some sort of permission system, not prevent the user from typing in URLs.

Comment: can you share us the code that you have tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to achieve it in this way:

- on every page looking for some $_POST value, for example `if (isset($_POST['refer']))`
- if isset the value that you're looking for print the page content, otherwise print error, redirect to homepage or do what you want to do when the user come in the page without clicking on your button
- modify your button, on click not only redirect the user but submit a form with the wanted post value

You can add your value directly into button value

```
<form action="/yourpage.php" method="post">
  <button name="subject" type="submit" value="VALUE_TO_SEND">BUTTON 
TEXT</button>
</form>
```

**VALUE_TO_SEND** can be: the current url, or what you want to use to check the refer

Comment: so should i make form for each button?

Comment: You can do a little form for each button or a single form with a lot of buttons and variable action, the first solutions is easier because not need the use javascript, wait I edit my answer with a small form example

Comment: There's a semantic and behavioural difference between GET and POST requests (most obviously seen if you try the back button in the browser to return to a POST page). Don't blindly replace every regular link with a POST form unless you really know what the consequences are and that you're okay with them.

Comment: i tried this way but i have a problem i make the form for button add "this will redirect me to add page" but when i make this the submit button from the main page make submit for the form on add page too. i don't know why?

Comment: I’m not understand very well, post your updated code